# Download Code VB

Tags: vb.net, youtube

I created a program which downloads videos from YouTube. The user inputs a YouTube video link and my program finds some element id's of that YouTube video and then opens [youtube-mp3.org](http://youtube-mp3.org) through my webrowser1. Now once the file is finished converting a new page pops in the users browser with the file ready to download. I want to have my program ask the user where to safe the file beforehand and then let the program automatically save it to the users destination.

Thanks

Comment: Not a proper answer, but I had to do something similar to this before, look at [Awesomium.NET](http://awesomium.com/) which fires a [Download event](http://awesomium.com/docs/1_6_3/sharp_api/html/5e96e389-a6ce-03fc-b41b-a7bd1a268a20.htm), as the WebBrowser control doesn't let you easily do this.

Comment: So the problem is asking for saving destination? That can be done with FolderBrowserDialog.